# How to show the logical relation between two Pandas dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-wrangling, venn-diagram, exploratory-data-analysis

I have two Pandas dataframes `df1` and `df2`, both have a column for keys, respectively labeled `id1` and `id2`. How could I simply show which are the keys that are common to both dataframes, those who are only in `df1` those which are only in `df2`? The idea would be to show a Venn diagram with

- the number of elements only in `df1`
- the number of elements only in `df2`
- the number of elements in `df1` and `df2`

A visual representation would be nice but not necessary.

Comment: What have you tried to compute the intersection and differences in columns?

Comment: I didn't try much, I was looking for set operations in Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be an [outer merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with an indicator column:

Let’s try with this simple example:

```
>>> df1
  id1
0   a
1   b
2   c
>>> df2
  id2
0   b
1   c
2   d
3   e
>>> mrg = pd.merge(df1['id1'].rename('id'), df2['id2'].rename('id'), on='id',
...                how='outer', indicator=True)
>>> mrg
  id      _merge
0  a   left_only
1  b        both
2  c        both
3  d  right_only
4  e  right_only
```

Now you get a column `id` with the ids, and a column `_merge` that tells you if they’re only in the left, the right, or in both dataframes.

Getting the number of elements is pretty easy from there:

```
>>> mrg['_merge'].value_counts()
right_only    2
both          2
left_only     1
Name: _merge, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to do it with three dataframes instead of two?
When I do `mrg = pd.merge(df1['id1'].rename('id'), df2['id2'].rename('id'), df3['id3'].rename('id'), on='id', how='outer', indicator=True)` I have the following error message : `merge() got multiple values for argument 'how'`.

Comment: @crocefisso `pd.merge` can only merge 2 dataframes

Comment: Yes I saw that. One option would be to do it 3 times, 1. with `df1` and `df2`, 2. with `df2` and `df3`, 3. with `df1` and `df3`.